# Anonymous type and getting values out side of method scope

Tags: c#-4.0, entity-framework-4, asp.net-4.0

I am building an asp.net site in .net framework 4.0, and I am stuck at the method that supposed to call a .cs class and get the query result back here is my method call and method

## 1: method call form aspx.cs page:

```
helper cls = new helper();
  var query = cls.GetQuery(GroupID,emailCap);
```

## 2: Method in helper class:

```
public IQueryable<VariablesForIQueryble> GetQuery(int incomingGroupID, int incomingEmailCap)
    {
        var ctx = new some connection_Connection();
        ObjectSet<Members1> members = ctx.Members11;
        ObjectSet<groupMember> groupMembers = ctx.groupMembers;

        var query = from m in members
                    join gm in groupMembers on m.MemberID equals gm.MemID
                    where (gm.groupID == incomingGroupID) && (m.EmailCap == incomingEmailCap)
                    select new VariablesForIQueryble(m.MemberID, m.MemberFirst, m.MemberLast, m.MemberEmail, m.ValidEmail, m.EmailCap);
                    //select new {m.MemberID, m.MemberFirst, m.MemberLast, m.MemberEmail, m.ValidEmail, m.EmailCap};

        return query ;
    }
```

I tried the above code with IEnumerable too without any luck. This is the code for class VariablesForIQueryble:

## 3:Class it self for taking anonymouse type and cast it to proper types:

```
public class VariablesForIQueryble
{
    private int _emailCap;
    public int EmailCap
    {
        get { return _emailCap; }
        set { _emailCap = value; }
    }`....................................
```

## 4: and a constructor:

```
 public VariablesForIQueryble(int memberID, string memberFirst, string memberLast, string memberEmail, int? validEmail, int? emailCap)
    {

            this.EmailCap = (int) emailCap;
            .........................

    }
```

I can't seem to get the query result back, first it told me anonymous type problem, I made a class after reading this: [link text](http://west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/33570.aspx); and now it tells me constructors with parameters not supported. Now I am an intermediate developer, is there an easy solution to this or do I have to take my query back to the .aspx.cs page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used reflection to solve the problem:

## A: Query, not using custom made "VariablesForIQueryble" class any more:

```
 //Method in helper class 
 public IEnumerable GetQuery(int incomingGroupID, int incomingEmailCap)
        {

            var ctx = new some_Connection();
            ObjectSet<Members1> members = ctx.Members11;
            ObjectSet<groupMember> groupMembers = ctx.groupMembers;

            var query = from m in members
                        join gm in groupMembers on m.MemberID equals gm.MemID
                        where ((gm.groupID == incomingGroupID) && (m.EmailCap == incomingEmailCap)) //select m;
                        select new {  m.MemberID,  m.MemberFirst,  m.MemberLast, m.MemberEmail,  m.ValidEmail, m.EmailCap };
                        //select new VariablesForIQueryble (m.MemberID, m.MemberFirst, m.MemberLast, m.MemberEmail, m.ValidEmail, m.EmailCap);
            //List<object> lst = new List<object>();

            //foreach (var i in query)
            //{
            //    lst.Add(i.MemberEmail);
            //}
            //return lst;
            //return query.Select(x => new{x.MemberEmail,x.MemberID,x.ValidEmail,x.MemberFirst,x.MemberLast}).ToList();
            return query;
        }
```

## B:Code to catch objects and conversion of those objects using reflection

```
  helper cls = new helper();
  var query = cls.GetQuery(GroupID,emailCap);      
 if (query != null)
                    {

                        foreach (var objRow in query)
                        {

                            System.Type type = objRow.GetType();
                            int memberId = (int)type.GetProperty("MemberID").GetValue(objRow, null);
                            string memberEmail = (string)type.GetProperty("MemberEmail").GetValue(objRow, null);
    }
    else
    {
    something else....
    }
```

Comment: I've tried this code too it's working but I think reflection are better
foreach(var objRow in query){
string[] objects  = objRow.ToString().Split(',');
                        foreach (var o in objects.Where(x=>x.Contains("@")))
                        {
                            if(o.Contains("@"))
                            {do something}
}}
but there were 2 loops and more work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to project to a specific type .NET type like this you will need to force the query to actually happen using either `.AsEnumerable()` or `.ToList()` and then use `.Select()` against linq to objects.

You could leave your original anonymous type in to specify what you want back from the database, then call `.ToList()` on it and then `.Select(...)` to reproject.

You can also clean up your code somewhat by using an Entity Association between Groups and Members using a FK association in the database.  Then the query becomes a much simpler:

```
var result = ctx.Members11.Include("Group").Where(m => m.Group.groupID == incomingGroupID && m.EmailCap == incomingEmailCap);
```

You still have the issue of having to do a select to specify which columns to return and then calling .ToList() to force execution before reprojecting to your new type.

Another alternative is to create a view in your database and import *that* as an Entity into the Entity Designer.

Comment: Thanks rider, I went for reflections here is the link where I got the code and the idea from:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/874746/how-can-i-get-a-value-of-a-property-from-an-anonymous-type
I was thinking of making view but that would be too much because I have multiple test tables and regular tables where I had to get the data from, the idea of foreign key associations is good but again I had test tables. I tired ToList() method it gave me problems. Finally I had to go for reflection. I appreciate your help very much sir.

Comment: If you are going to use weak-typing like that you might as well use the new `dynamic` type in .NET 4 to get to the various fields on the result object.  `.ToList()` should have worked fine: `(...query...).ToList().Select(x => new VariablesForIQuerable(...)).ToList();`